# Bootstrap Button click event with Jquery override

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am prototyping a new website using Bootstrap 3 and jQuery.

I have run into a problem with the click event of a button in that it works once...only.  The Click event is overridden in jQuery and I think that is where the problem lies...not jQuery, but my knowledge of jQuery.

The HTML code is...

```
<div class="row" id="bigCallout">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <!-- Alert Block to show when Bloody Big Button pressed -->
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block fade in" id="successAlert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

                    <h4>Success!</h4>
                    <p>You just made this element display by using jQuery. Click the 'x' to close this bad boy!</p>                     
                </div><!-- end alert-block -->

                <!-- Visible only on small devices -->
                <div class="well well-sm visible-sm">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"> Give Us a Call!</span></a>
                </div><!-- end well-sm -->
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>A Fancy Header. <small>A subheading for extra awesomeness...dood!</small></h1>                  
                    </div><!-- end page-header -->
                    <p class="lead">Some catchy copy to get your users engaged . Use this area to come up with something nice and convincing.  Know what I'm saying?</p>

                    <!-- Bloody Big Button to set the alert Block -->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id='alertMe'>A Bloody Big Button</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-link">...or a secondary link</a>
                </div><!-- end well -->
            </div><!-- end col-md-12 -->

        </div><!-- end bigCallout -->
```

And the jQuery code for the button click is...

```
$(function(){

 //Big Button click event
  $("#alertMe").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#successAlert").slideDown();
    });
});
```

At this time this action can happen one-time only and I need help to allow it to be repeated without refreshing the screen.

Comment: What is happening? When successAlert element has been open, it remains open even if you click a second time. If you remove successAlert by clicking on a close button inside, it is also normal that you cannot display a removed element a seconde time.

Comment: Are you closing the alert with the X?  If so, that *removes* the alert block from the DOM entirely so `successAlert` will no longer exist and the script will no longer do anything.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again

Comment: You should add a timer to it and then hide the element again if you want it to use it.

Comment: Have you looked at the numerous questions relating to JQuery click events only occurring once? Such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347229/jquery-ajax-call-on-click-only-works-once and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332450/jquery-ajax-call-on-click-only-works-once and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057707/jquery-and-ajax-on-click-only-works-once (There are more if you do a search of "JQuery on click only works once.)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I am removing the Alert with the 'x', so it looks like what I need to do is change the data-dismiss to a data-hide.

Comment: The click event routine looks OK to me as it just overrides the default.  Do I need to write a jquery routine for the HIDE or does Bootstrap handle that?

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I pieced it together and as I suspected, added the hide routine.  All is well now.
Something new learned today...bonus!